# Using SSH to connect to an Ubuntu Server to develop remotely. How can I actually run my programs and see visual outputs?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-server

So I am using VSCode Insiders to connect via SSH to my Ubuntu Server where I have all my project clones. Everything up to here works so far. I am doing a bit of pandas/matplotlib in python and say, I wanted to plot a graph and see it. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to view graphical linux applications over SSH, you need to do a couple of things. First of all, you need to make sure that your Ubuntu Server is running an X windows server so the system knows how to process GUI events. Once you've verified this, you need to configure your SSH client to communicate with the X windows server. This will vary based on your host operating system and the SSH client you're using.

This guide could be helpful:
https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/x11-forwarding

Comment: When answering questions on the Stack Exchange network, you should supply all the information with your answer. You should avoid telling folks to follow off-site links.